# Does port number affect peers when using torrents?

Tags: filesystems, file-transfer, file-sharing, utorrent

Does port number have any affect on the selection of peers when using torrent software, and if so what affect does it have?

Comment: You need to be specific, which port are you referring to, your port for incoming connections or do you mean the port you use to create outgoing connections?

Comment: Some peers block certain low port numbers for leachers as they are an indication of a inexperienced user. (default for some clients is 6881) Ports between 49152-65534 are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. The caveat is if your ISP is doing some *really* dumb filtering based on port, which is highly unlikely.